# Loop through a multilevel JSON object having children of same name

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have a JSON object as follows.

```
{
    "name":"Me",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name":"My Garage",
            "groups":[
                {
                    "name":"My Cars",
                    "groups":[],
                    "tags":[
                        {
                            "name":"Fiet Punto"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Gallardo"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"My Bikes",
                    "groups":[]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"My Bank",
            "groups":[
                {
                    "name":"Swiss Bank",
                    "groups":[]
                },
                {
                    "name":"Bank of America",
                    "groups":[],
                    "tags":[
                        {
                            "name":"Account 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Account 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tags":[
        {
            "name":"My tag 1"
        },
        {
            "name":"My tag 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
Me
--My Garage
  --My Cars
    --Fiet Punto
    --Gallardo
  --My Bikes
--My Bank
  --Swiss Bank
  --Bank of America
    -- Account 1
    -- Account 2
--My Tag 1
--My Tag 2
```

I have a problem in building the recursion. What I want to do is:

- Take the root object.
- Print the `name`.
- Find if `groups` or `tags` exist in the object.
- if any of them exist then loop through the inner object.
- Apply the correct indentation and follow the steps above for the inner object.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT :

```
function getAllGroups(jsonObject)
{

    //print the name of the current level object.
    $("body").append(jsonObject.name);

    //now if this object contains groups
    if( jsonObject.hasOwnProperty( 'groups' ) )
    {
        //and if it is an array
        if( jsonObject.groups.length > 0 )
        {
            //then for each object in groups of this object, call the function again.
            $(jsonObject.groups).each(function(i, innerObject){
                //print the index for debugging.
                console.log(i + innerObject.name);
                //make a recursive call to the function.
                getAllGroups(innerObject);

            });

        }

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("does not exist anymore.")
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out how can I evaluate both `tags` and `groups` in parallel and print the names maintaining the level.

More precisely I am not being able to figure out how to get the level of the tree.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. What *exactly* are you having troubles with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the level of the tree, i think the simplest way is just to pass the current level to the method:

```
function getAllGroups(jsonObject,currentlevel)
{

    //print the name of the current level object.
    $("body").append(jsonObject.name);

    //now if this object contains groups
    if( jsonObject.hasOwnProperty( 'groups' ) )
    {
        //and if it is an array
        if( jsonObject.groups.length > 0 )
        {
            var nextlevel = currentlevel+1;
            //then for each object in groups of this object, call the function again.
            $(jsonObject.groups).each(function(i, innerObject){
                //print the index for debugging.
                console.log(i + innerObject.name);
                //make a recursive call to the function.
                getAllGroups(innerObject,nextlevel);

            });

        }

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("does not exist anymore.")
    }
}
```

Use it by initiating the first level:

```
getAllGroups(yourJSON,1);
```

Comment: did so! but no help.. not getting proper levels

Comment: @pjp: the idea is to just pass the current level to the method. How you manage your current level is up to you. The code above is just an example. Well, but i think it should fit your requirement. Could you check again if any thing else is wrong? Hope you find out soon.